# Why does the PE becomes negative in potential energy versus intermolecular distance graph?

Tags: energy, intermolecular-forces

In the potential energy versus inter molecular distance graph, we know that atoms/molecules/particles want to be at optimum distance from each other ie *$r_0$* and to the left of this position in the graph, we get the repulsive force and to the right would be the attractive force acting between them.

Note: Inter-molecular distance is denoted by ‘r’.

However, I have the following questions regarding this graph:

Why does graph represent negative Potential energy after a certain inter-molecular distance ?

What does negative potential energy mean in this context since the repulsive energy at r=0 was positive?

What happens at the point when P.E. becomes zero for a certain inter-molecular distance?

If the P.E. at that point has already reached zero, why is there a further need to go into negative potential energy?
[image: The graph itself]

Comment: @Poutnik, I do understand that part but this analogy doesn't seem to fit into what I was wondering. Why does even some negative PE show repulsion as well? Shouldn't it have been that all negative PE=attraction and bonding while all of the positive PE=repulsion?

Comment: What's happening where the PE=0?

Comment: Well, a marble ball does roll down even along the pit wall. it does not need to be a hill slope. For attraction/repulsion,  important is the PE gradient along the path.  What happens at PE=0 depends on the sign and value of d(PE)/dx.

Comment: The zero energy level is by convention the situation where the particles are infinitely far away from one another.

Comment: Helpful will be reviewing the very basics about potential and potential energy around classical central electrostatic and gravitational force.

Comment: @Maurice, The PE is zero at a short distance too. Why is that?

Comment: @M. Farooq. No. At short distance, the PE is small, nearly zero. But it is not zero !

Comment: @Maurice, I am talking about the point where PE curve crosses the zero line before becoming too large.

Comment: @ M. Farooq. Which point ? Never heard of it.

Comment: @Maurice You cannot be serious. You have it directly before your eyes if you look at the picture the OP posted. When atoms get too close, they start to repulse each other, the negative PE starts climbing, crossing the zero point and finally becomes positive.

Comment: @Poutnik. OK. Thank you. I was not thinking about this point. I was thinking of some strange phenomena at longer distances, a little bit like the maximum happening when ionic $\ce{NaCl}$ is extended and transformed into neutral atoms. There is a PE maximum at about three or four times the equilibrium distance.

Comment: @Maurice Thanks. I did suspect you might meant something else, as you could not miss this triviality.