# Energy of reactants and products

Tags: energy, stability

In some reactions, energy is released and when I want to understand the reason for the release of energy, I find that the energy of the products is lower than that of the reactants.
But What is this energy difference caused by?
It is written in various sources that this energy difference is due to the potential energy difference, But what is potential energy?
Other sources make it clear that the high energy of the reactants causes instability, What exactly does this high energy describe? When we say that the energy of the reactants is higher, does it mean that the bond energy is higher? Well, if so, why is it necessary to break strong bonds in the reactants and weak bonds are formed in the products?
I would be grateful if you could explain the matter to me completely and clearly.

Comment: Related:  https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/157655/why-does-the-pe-becomes-negative-in-potential-energy-versus-intermolecular-dista?noredirect=1#comment322805_157655

Comment: Unfortunately this is much too broad for this site. Please consult a general chemistry book. If you have trouble with any concepts you encounter, you are welcome to ask more detailed questions here. Essentially you are asking here: What is Chemistry and why and how does it work?

Answer (score 1):

- Creation of a chemical bond releases energy ( and vice versa ).
- This released energy is different for different bonds.
- If breaking bonds of reactants takes less total energy than there is released by forming of product bonds, the reaction releases energy ( and vice versa ).
- The source of energy is combined kinetic energy and electrostatic potential energy of valence electrons.
- Potential energy is energy needed to move a free object ( away of external forces ) to the place of the interest ( is negative when energy is released ).
- When reaction energy is released, valence electrons gain in average more negative potential energy. The means more energy is needed to release such electrons from a molecule.